# Deploying to Heroku with node.js & express - how to setup connection to mongoLab?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mlab

Alright, first time posting here, so I'm hoping I get some feedback.

- I have two collections that I've successfully uploaded into
  mongoLab/mLab, their names are "allTest" and "myCollection".
- I want to deploy my site to heroku (which I've successfully done
  already) and be able to pull and display data from mLab.
- Everything was working great when I was running locally and pulling
  from mongoDB, so I know its because I want to pull from mLab instead of my local instance of mongoDB. However, I'm confused on how to setup the connection to mLab when its deployed on Heroku.
- I've read some documentation that I should use URI (which I listed below),
  but I'm not sure what else I should change in my code.

Here is what I have so far (I edited out my username and password in the URI):

```
var express = require("express");
var mongojs = require("mongojs");
var logger = require("morgan");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser());


 var uri = 'mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ds157702.mlab.com:57702/heroku_r45mjcns';


app.use(express.static("public"));


var databaseUrl = "mydb";
var collections = ["myCollection"];

var databaseUrl2 = "testMenu";
var collections2 = ["allTests"];


var db = mongojs(databaseUrl, collections);
var db2 = mongojs(databaseUrl2, collections2);


app.get("/", function(req, res) { 
   res.sendfile('public/home.html');
});


app.get("/find2/:id", function(req, res) {
  var test_id2 = req.param('id');



  db2.allTests.find({"TestName": {$regex:test_id2, $options: 'i'} }, function(error, found) {
    // Log any errors if the server encounters one
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    // Otherwise, send the result of this query to the browser
    else {
      res.json(found);
      console.log("From server");
      console.log(found);

    }
  });
  });




app.get("/find/:id", function(req, res) {
  var test_id = req.param('id');

  db2.allTests.find({"Test": test_id }, function(error, found) {
    // Log any errors if the server encounters one
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    // Otherwise, send the result of this query to the browser
    else {
      res.json(found);
      console.log("From server");
      console.log(found);

    }
  });
  });





  app.get("/find/dept/:id", function(req, res) {
  var test_id = req.param('id');

  db.myCollection.find({ $or: [ { "WebsiteCategory": test_id }, { "WebsiteCategory2": test_id } ] }, function(error, found) {
    // Log any errors if the server encounters one
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    // Otherwise, send the result of this query to the browser
    else {
      res.json(found);
      console.log("From server");
      console.log(found);

    }
  });
  });







  app.get("/find/dept2/:id", function(req, res) {
  var test_id = req.param('id');

  db.myCollection.find({"TestSet": test_id }, function(error, found) {
    // Log any errors if the server encounters one
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    // Otherwise, send the result of this query to the browser
    else {
      res.json(found);
      console.log("From server");
      console.log(found);

    }
  });
  });







// Set the app to listen on port 3000
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

`

Specifically, its this piece of code that I was trying out:

```
     app.get("/find/dept/:id", function(req, res) {
  var test_id = req.param('id');

  db.myCollection.find({ $or: [ { "WebsiteCategory": test_id }, { "WebsiteCategory2": test_id } ] }, function(error, found) {
    // Log any errors if the server encounters one
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    // Otherwise, send the result of this query to the browser
    else {
      res.json(found);
      console.log("From server");
      console.log(found);

    }
  });
  });
```

Any help would be appreciated!!